# positioning from inside directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a directive that shows an overlay over the entire page, with positioning "absolute" to top 0, left 0.

I do not want the overlay to be fixed positioned, but to scroll with the site.

Because I need access to elements from a controller, I have the directive element "buried" in relative elements. Is there a way for me to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried other types of positioning? as `fixed` or `static`?

Comment: Can you provide code example? scope variables doesn't disappear when they are scrolled away, you are more likely facing a variable passing issue.

Answer (score 0):

As other positioning did not work, I ended up creating a proxy-directive (which actually contains some html code in this case) which I compile and append to the body tag, circumventing the problem:

```
.directive('proxy',['$compile','$document','$rootScope',function($compile,$document,$rootScope){
    return {
      templateUrl: 'proxy.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var body = $document.find('body').eq(0);
        if(!$rootScope.proxy) {
          var expl = $compile("<actual-directive></actual-directive>")(scope);
          body.append(expl);
          $rootScope.proxy = true;
        }
      }
    };
  }])
```

Not too nice adding a property to $rootScope, but it prevents the directive from opening more than once